# Python class and object error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting error while running the program

```
Enter the length of the rectangle: 4
Enter the width of the rectangle: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Shourav\Desktop\rectangle_startfile.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Shourav\Desktop\rectangle_startfile.py", line 34, in main
    my_rect = Rectangle()
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'length' and 'width'
```

Code:

```
# class definition

class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, length, width):

        self.__length = length
        self.__width = width
        self.__area = area

    def set_length(self, length):
        self.__length = length

    def set_width(self, width):
        self.__width = width

    def get_length(self, length):
        return self.__length

    def get_width(self, width):
        return self.__width

    def get_area(self, length, width):
        area = (length * width)
        self.__area = area
        return self.__area


# main function
def main():

    length = int(input("Enter the length of the rectangle: "))
    width = int(input("Enter the width of the rectangle: "))

    my_rect = Rectangle()

    my_rect.set_length(length)
    my_rect.set_width(width)

    print('The length is',my_rect.get_length())
    print('The width is', my_rect.get_width())

    print('The area is',my_rect.get_area())
    print(my_rect)

    input('press enter to continue')


# Call the main function

main()
```

Comment: Hi, I am a beginner in python programming. This is my first program for object and class was having problem accessing the class file

Answer (score 3):

You defined a `Rectangle` class whose initializer method requires two arguments:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
```

yet you try to create one *without* passing in those arguments:

```
my_rect = Rectangle()
```

Pass in a length and width instead:

```
my_rect = Rectangle(length, width)
```

Your next problem is that `area` is not defined, you probably want to calculate that:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.__length = length
        self.__width = width
        self.get_area(length, width)
```

On a design note: normally in Python you do not use 'private' variables like that; simply use normal attributes instead:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width
```

and *directly* get or set those attributes on the instance as needed:

```
print('The length is', my_rect.length)
print('The width is', my_rect.width)
print('The area is', my_rect.area)
```

Attributes that start with a double underscore (`__name`) are meant to avoid subclasses from accidentally redefining them; the aim is to protect those attributes from being clobbered because they are vital to the internal working of the current class. The fact that their names get mangled and thus are less accessible does not really make them private, just harder to reach. Whatever you do, do not mistake them for private names like you would in Java, for example.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `my_rect = Rectangle()` it needs `length` and `width` to be passed to it as stated in the `Rectangle __init__` method.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Rectangle requires two arguments which you do not set.

See:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, length, width):
```

and

```
    my_rect = Rectangle()
```

You need:

```
    my_rect = Rectangle(length, width)
```

Just for your info:

the self parameter in the constructor is a parameter which will be passed implicitly so you do not to pass it (at least not by implementing it in the code).

Answer (score 0):

The way you've defined `__init__` in your `Rectangle` class requires you call it with a length and width:

```
def __init__(self, length, width):
```

Change

```
my_rect = Rectangle()

my_rect.set_length(length)
my_rect.set_width(width)
```

to

```
my_rect = Rectangle(length, width)
```